# What is the difference between explicit atomic load/store and usual operator= and operator T?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdatomic

Consider these two variants:

```
std::atomic<int> a;
a = 1;
int b = a;
```

and

```
std::atomic<int> a;
a.store(1);
int b = a.load();
```

I see from the documentation that the second one is fully atomic, but I don't understand when I should use which and what's the difference in detail.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Those two examples are equivalent; `operator=` and `operator T` are defined to be equivalent to calling `store` and `load` respectively, with the default value for the `memory_order` argument.

If you're happy with that default value, `memory_order_seq_cst`, so that each access acts as a memory fence, then use whichever looks nicer to you. If you want to specify a different value, then you'll need to use the functions, since the operators can't accept a second argument.

Comment: Worth noting that `memory_order_seq_cst` is the strongest memory ordering. There's no reason to specify a different one, other than to improve performance in situations where you don't need full sequential consistency.

Comment: I prefer `load` / `store` because it indicates the variable is an atomic one, it enhances code readability!